# Is there a way to add elements of a list to a dataframe that already has elements in it in a specific format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this
[image]

and a list (temp_bucket) that looks like this:

[image]

and I've tried to insert the elements of the list to the dataframe with this code:

```
       k = 0
       while k < len(temp_bucket):
           for row in range(1, math.floor(len(temp_bucket) / sensors) + 1):
               for col in range(0, sensors):
                   chunk.at[row, col] = temp_bucket[k] 
           k += 1
```

hoping for:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  0  22 23 31
1  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  1  0
```

but I keep getting this no matter how I frame the loops:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  0  22 23 31
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
```

Thank you for your help! (sorry I just started learning python in last couple of months)

Comment: Initialize the dataframe in the sample script. We should be able to copy and run your code.

Comment: pls see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0):

let's reshape your list then make dataframe out of it and then append:

```
temp_bucket=list(map(int,'101000001010'))
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(temp_bucket).values.reshape(3,4)),ignore_index=True)
#OR(via concat() method)
#df=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(temp_bucket).values.reshape(3,4))],ignore_index=True)
```

output of `df`:

```
    0       1       2       3
0   0.0     22.0    23.0    31.0
1   1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3   1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
```

**Note:** If you want integer values then chain `astype(int)` to above code but it will throw error if your dataframe has missing values

```
#df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(temp_bucket).values.reshape(3,4)),ignore_index=True).astype(int)


#output:

    0   1   2   3
0   0   22  23  31
1   1   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   1   0   1   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking to accomplish. I'll have to dig further into pandas' functions to further my knowledge.

Comment: @samesame if it helped then you can try considering accepting this as an answer to indicate others that the issue is solved(click on the tick to make it green)...Thanks **:)**